# Use Actor Class both local and remote

Tags: python, local, remote-access, ray

I want to use class in both local/single-process and remote/multi-process scenarios.
What I got so far is :

```
@ray.remote
class BlahRemote(Blah): pass

class Blah(object):

   def save(self,line):
      if self.is_writer : self.file.write(line)
      else : self.writer.save.remote(line)
```

what I wanna do is something like this :

```
   def save(self,line):
      if self.is_writer : self.file.write(line)
      else :
        if RAY.ISREMOTE(self.writer) : self.writer.save.remote(line)
        else : self.writer.save(line)
```

is there a way to do this check RAY.ISREMOTE()

Answer (score 0):

What i did is this (replace save() with set(), used example with files earlier cause its easer to grasp)

Surprisingly there are 3 cases not 2, missed the case where both Reader and Writer are in the same process.

```
def set(self,key,value): 
    if self.is_writer : 
        say('kvset', f'local-writer-set> {key} => {value}')
        self.store.set_kv(key, value)
    else : 
        if str(self.writer).startswith('Actor') :
            say('kvset', f'remote-set> {key} => {value}')
            self.writer.set.remote(key, value)
        else :
            say('kvset', f'local-reader-set> {key} => {value}')
            self.writer.set(key, value)
```